Add label to all thursdays beside events in react big calendar
i am using react big calendar, i want to add a custom label to all thusdays. i use components day header but it removes all events in calendar
here is my code
      <Calendar
        selectable={true}
        localizer={newLocalizer}
        culture={'fa'}
        startAccessor='start'
        endAccessor='end'
        style={{ height: 500 }}
        formats={configs.formats}
        messages={configs.messages}
        views={configs.views}
        rtl={configs.rtl}
        events={events}
        onSelectSlot={handleSlotSelect}
        eventPropGetter={eventStyleGetter}
        components={{
          event: MyMonthEvent,
          month: {
            dateHeader: MyMonthDateHeader,
            event: MyMonthEvent
          }
        }}
      />

and here is my dateHeader component
import React from 'react'

function MyMonthDateHeader(props) {
  const dayOfWeek = props.date.getDay()
  const style = {
    color: dayOfWeek === 5 ? 'red' : 'black'
  }
  return (
    <div style={style}>
      {props.label}
      {dayOfWeek === 4 && (
        <div>
          <p>gym day</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyMonthDateHeader


i try using dateHeader component but it removes all my events, i expect to show my events beside this custom label too

Try this:
const dayOfWeek = date.getDay()
// const dayOfWeek = props.date.getDay()


it's does not work and it isn't relevant to my question
